# Show that ~(A XOR B) is the same as (~A XOR B) using Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-expression

I need to show that the expression:

```
~(A XOR B)
```

is equivilant to

```
(~A XOR B)
```

using boolean algebra.

I really have no idea how to start, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Construct a truth table for each expression.

Comment: Maybe start with this: what is `(A XOR ~A)`?

Comment: As it says in the OP I need to use Boolean algebra to show they are equivilant. A truth table does show it is equivilant but not using Boolean algebra.

Comment: There is a rule to expand (A XOR B) to get 2 simpler clauses that make use of only the OR and AND operator. Once you reach this step, you can "move" the NOT operator in, do some manipulation, and use the same rule you used to write your expression back in terms of XOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that two logical expressions are equivalent, you may proceed in two different ways.

1. Write a [truth table](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/math-proof/truth-tables/truth-tables.html) for each of the expressions and then, if the resulting functional truth values are the same, then the expressions are equivalent;
2. Equivalence is the same as implication in both directions;

   > A <=> B  is equivalent to  (A => B) AND (B => A)

   So, what you need is try to get (~A xor B) from ~(A xor B) and vice versa.

   - **~(A xor B)** =
   - by definition of xor + negation =  **~ ( (~A and B) or (A and ~B) )** =
   - by De Morgan law = **~ (~A and B) and ~(A and ~B)** =
   - by De Morgan law again = **(A or ~B) and (~A or B)** =
   - by applying distributive law = **(A and ~A) or (A and B) or (~B and ~A) or (~B and B)** =
   - ignore contradictions = **(A and B) or (~B and ~A)** =
   - apply definition of xor in another direction = **~A xor B**.

   **the end**

   The same procedure must be done in the other direction ( get ~(A xor B) from (~A xor B) ). Then the proof will be complete.